# How to use state of array with dynamic number of elements

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-state-management

I am developing an application to add questions for a quiz in React.js in which I am taking number of options of a MCQ as input from user which in turn renders that number of input tags. But I am not able to make those inputs controlled using state. I have created a state of array (to make the inputs controlled) but I cannot initialize it as I don't know the number of elements it will contain and if I change number of options again I get this message

> index.js:1 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to
> be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from
> undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between
> using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of
> the component.

and starts giving weird bugs. The rendering logic is as follows where options=[] is the state.

```
<Form.Group key={i} className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
    <Form.Control
        value={options[i]}
        onChange={(e) => {
            setOptions((prev) => {
                let previous = [...prev]
                previous[i] = e.target.value
                return previous
            })
        }}
        type="text"
        placeholder={`Option ${i + 1}`} 
        className="options"
        />
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a fallback value for your inputs for the initially `undefined` value, thus they stay controlled all the time. Since you have `type='text'`, empty string `''` seems like the ideal initial value. You can do it like below:

```
 value={options[i] || ''}
```